# How to add editor to the textarea in my custom component in joomla 2.5?

Tags: text-editor, joomla2.5

I have created a custom component in joomla 2.5 where the fields are creating in an xml file.
Here is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <field
            name="id"
            type="hidden"
        />
        <field
            name="title"
            type="text"
            label="Title"
            description="This is the title"
            size="40"
            class="inputbox"
            default=""
            style="width:294px;height:135px;"
        />
        <field
            name="description"
            type="textarea"
            label="Description"
            description="This is the description"
            rows="20"
            cols="10"
            class="inputbox"
            default=""
        />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to the description text area to be an editor just like in the new article form.
How will I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem.
Just change the type of the description field.

```
<field
        name="description"
        type="editor"
        label="Description"
        description="This is the description"
        filter="safehtml"
        class="inputbox"
        default=""
    />
```